# WebView2: navigating to second page causes remote messenger error

Tags: webview2

Navigating the webview2 browser to a web page with host objects bound, making calls to window.chrome.webview.hostObjects, and then later navigating to another page seems to reprocess existing remote messenger responses, which then generates a host of javascript errors because the response has already been processed. This seems like a bug with webview2 or am I doing something wrong? Is there presently a workaround?

```
VM6:1 Assertion failed: no call detail for 98
_handleResponse @   VM6:1
(anonymous) @   VM6:1
(anonymous) @   VM7:1
(anonymous)
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect this is a bug. It looks like you've already filed it as [an issue in the WebView2Feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/836) which is the correct place to file such bugs. The WebView2 team will need to look into it. Thanks.